# Calculation does not return the correct value

Tags: javascript, html

can anyone tell me what is the error on this javascript code?

Program:  http://utilizaweb.com.br/aposentadorianovo/

```
function calcula(){
var fieldsContainer=document.getElementsByClassName("trabalho")[0].
                             getElementsByClassName("row"),
    i,
    jobFields=[],
    len,
    newAge=0,
    selfGender=document.aposentadoria.sexo.value,
    workedDays=0,
    workedMonthies=0,
    workedYears=0;
len=fieldsContainer.length;
for(i=0;len>i;i++){
    jobFields[i]={
        admissionDate:new Date(fieldsContainer[i].getElementsByClassName("admissao-area")[0].children[1].value),//data de admissÃ£o,
        ageRule:fieldsContainer[i].getElementsByClassName("regra-area")[0].children[0].value,//regra
        demissionDate:new Date(fieldsContainer[i].getElementsByClassName("demissao-area")[0].children[1].value),//data de demissÃ£o
        jobBusiness:fieldsContainer[i].getElementsByClassName("empresa-area")[0].children[1].value//empresa do trabalho
    };
    if (jobFields[i].demissionDate > jobFields[i].admissionDate) {
        jobFields[i].workedYears=jobFields[i].demissionDate.getFullYear() - jobFields[i].admissionDate.getFullYear();
        jobFields[i].workedMonthies=jobFields[i].demissionDate.getMonth() - jobFields[i].admissionDate.getMonth();
        jobFields[i].workedDays=jobFields[i].demissionDate.getDate() - jobFields[i].admissionDate.getDate();
        alert(jobFields[i].workedYears)
    } else {
        alert("A data de admissÃ£o deve ser anterior Ã  data de demissÃ£o.");
        throw new Error("Conversor :: Admission date must be older than demission date.")
    }
}
var fieldsRule=[];
len=jobFields.length;
for(i=0;len>i;i++){
    fieldsRule[i]=jobFields[i].ageRule
}
var calculateFields=[],
    higherRule=Math.max.apply(fieldsRule)
len=jobFields.length;
for(i=0;len>i;i++){
    if(fieldsRule[i]===higherRule){
        calculateFields[i]=i
    }
}
var ageMultiplyBy,
    missingYears,
    jobYearsEnd;
len=calculateFields.length;
if (selfGender === "M") {
    for(i=0;len>i;i++){
        ageMultiplyBy=
                    jobFields[calculateFields[i]].ageRule==="25"?1.40:
                    jobFields[calculateFields[i]].ageRule==="20"?1.75:
                    jobFields[calculateFields[i]].ageRule==="15"?2.33:
                    1.75;
        newAge=jobFields[calculateFields[i]].workedYears*ageMultiplyBy;
        missingYears=newAge - 35
    }
} else {
    for(i=0;len>i;i++){
        ageMultiplyBy=
                    jobFields[calculateFields[i]].ageRule==="25"?1.20:
                    jobFields[calculateFields[i]].ageRule==="20"?1.50:
                    jobFields[calculateFields[i]].ageRule==="15"?2:
                    1.20;
        newAge=jobFields[calculateFields[i]].workedYears*ageMultiplyBy;
        missingYears=newAge - 30
    }
}

alert(missingYears)
if (missingYears < 0) {
    jobYearsEnd=missingYears * -1;
}
document.getElementById("anosTrabalhados").innerHTML = workedYears+ " anos";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<img src='./img/aviso.png'>" +"VocÃª trabalhou " +workedYears+ " anos, " +workedMonthies+ " meses e " +workedDays+ " dias"+ "<br />" +"Faltam " +jobYearsEnd+ " anos para se aposentar"
}
```

[IF WASN'T WELL EXPLAINED, PLEASE TELL ME. I DONT SPEAK ENGLISH SO WELL]

I need get the value of the admissionDate and of the demissionDate and subtract of each line, including those added by the user. Then, I need get the biggest values of rules are equal, and add up the time worked in each one. Then, the program takes the time worked added up and multiply by the value of each rule and subtract of 35 in case of male and of 30 in case of female. And then displays the value calculated last (minus 30 or 35).

Where the code is wrong?

Look the code by View Source

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "and subtract of each line".  Can you explain that better?

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly within the post rather than a link to it. ([Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)) Preferably include the [minimal portion of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: for example, the user has posted 4 companies in which it works, I need to know the time worked in each of them.

Comment: Please reformat your code to be more readable.

Comment: Please elaborate the meaning of "I need get the biggest values of rules are equal..." does that mean only use the largest value?  And then you say "..., and add up the time worked in each one" - for each one what?  And then "time worked added up and multiply by the value of each rule".

Answer (score 0):

I did what I could with this one as there are several challenges and a couple of points where I am not 100 percent sure your intent.  I believe you can work from here.  Date stuff is hard when you work with multiple related dates.  What if the boundary crosses daylight savings time etc. To assist with that I used a date library, feel free to get another or use it, I pasted it into the fiddle code; use it or get another that does that stuff rather than re-invent one. I did not use it extensively.

Here is a saved fiddle to test/try it out: (see the bottom for the good parts) https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/1ttmecoe/

Link the the date library: http://slingfive.com/pages/code/jsDate/jsDate.html

## Explanation:

First off, your undisclosed code replicates an ID and those MUST be unique, and when you use that it is in error.  I fixed that by using jQuery `.clone()`  I also put a method to add/remove rows (all but last one) from your list) which was lacking on your page.

Code snip:

```
document.getElementById("anosTrabalhados").innerHTML
```

I will show you how to fix that (see the markup and `.clone()`)

- You have some rather complex selectors which can be simplified by the use of classes.

Code snip:

```
jobFields[i]={
    admissionDate:new Date(fieldsContainer[i].getElementsByClassName("admissao-area")[0].children[1].value),//data de admissÃ£o,
```

revised:

```
var thisRow = fieldsContainer[i];
jobFields[i] = {
  admissionDate: new Date(thisRow.getElementsByClassName("dataAdmissao")[0].value),
```

- Checking/validation of dates right in the middle of a loop, perhaps you might check those before you loop? I left that for now as it was.

Code snip:

```
if (jobFields[i].demissionDate > jobFields[i].admissionDate) {
```

This appears to be a syntax issue here:

```
higherRule=Math.max.apply(fieldsRule) //old
higherRule=Math.max.apply(null, fieldsRule); //repaired
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

- Remove constants from code and put them in an object:

Code snip:

```
var calcVals = {
  rules: {
    male: {
      sex: "M",
      defaultRate: 1.75,
      ageVar: 35,
      ageRules: [{
        age: "25",
        val: 1.40
      }, {
        age: "20",
        val: 1.75
      }, {
        age: "15",
        val: 2.33
      }]
    },
    female: {
      sex: "M",
      defaultRate: 1.50,
      ageVar: 30,
      ageRules: [{
        age: "25",
        val: 1.20
      }, {
        age: "20",
        val: 1.50
      }, {
        age: "15",
        val: 2.00
      }]
    }
  }
};
```

then use it later: (this gets rid of the duplicate hard coded conditional making it simpler and more maintainable)

```
calcT = (selfGender === "M") ? calcT = calcVals.rules.male : calcT = calcVals.rules.female;
ageMultiplyBy = calcT.defaultRate;
for (i = 0; len > i; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < calcT.ageRules.length; j++) {
    if (jobFields[calculateFields[i]].ageRule === calcT.ageRules[j].age) {
      ageMultiplyBy = calcT.ageRules[j].val;
      break;
    }
  }
  ...more code
```

- Assignment of a string to an array

Code snip:

```
fieldsRule[i]=jobFields[i].ageRule
```

This changes this comparison: (see the next code segment as well)

```
if(fieldsRule[i]===higherRule){
```

The `fieldsRule[i]` is a string and `higherRule` is a numeric (see the `Math.max.apply` above)

You set the iteration variable `len` based on `jobFields` but access the `fieldsRule[i]` which MIGHT be undefined.  Did you mean to push to the array rather than assign to it? I ask because later on you use `len=calculateFields.length;` as an iterate value. Note that all the `fieldsRule[i]` might not be evaluated if the lengths differ on the arrays OR it might have an `undefined` value. (note that this is where your desired functionality becomes less clear)

```
len=jobFields.length;
for(i=0;len>i;i++){
    if(fieldsRule[i]===higherRule){
        calculateFields[i]=i
    }
}
```

See this later down: `newAge=jobFields[calculateFields[i]].workedYears*ageMultiplyBy;` where `calculateFields[i]` might be undefined.

### Revised markup:

```
<form class="form-calculadora" name="aposentadoria">
  <fieldset class="sexo">
    <legend>Sexo</legend>
    <select id="sexo" class="text-area">
      <option value="M">Masculino</option>
      <option value="F">Feminino</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="trabalho">
    <div class="row p_scents">
      <div class="empresa-area">
        <p class="title">Empresa</p>
        <input type="text" class="text-area empresa" placeholder="Empresa: ">
      </div>
      <div class="regra-area">
        <p class="title">Regra</p>
        <select class="text-area regra">
          <option value="25">25 anos</option>
          <option value="20">20 anos</option>
          <option value="15">15 anos</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="admissao-area">
        <p class="title">Admissão</p>
        <input type="date" class="text-area dataAdmissao" placeholder="Admissão: " />
      </div>
      <div class="demissao-area">
        <p class="title">Demissão</p>
        <input type="date" class="text-area dataDemissao" placeholder="Demissão: " />
      </div>
      <div class="anos-area">
        <p class="anosTrabalhados">0 anos</p>
      </div>
      <button class="removerow">
        Remove Row
      </button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <p class="add-empresa"><a href="#" id="addScnt"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Adicionar Empresa</a></p>
  <p id="result">Você trabalhou 0 anos, 0 meses e 0 dias
    <br/>Faltam undefined anos para se aposentar</p>
  <input type="button" value="Calcular" class="btn" id="calcular" />
</form>
```

### Revised code:

```
var calcVals = {
  rules: {
    male: {
      sex: "M",
      defaultRate: 1.75,
      ageVar: 35,
      ageRules: [{
        age: "25",
        val: 1.40
      }, {
        age: "20",
        val: 1.75
      }, {
        age: "15",
        val: 2.33
      }]
    },
    female: {
      sex: "M",
      defaultRate: 1.50,
      ageVar: 30,
      ageRules: [{
        age: "25",
        val: 1.20
      }, {
        age: "20",
        val: 1.50
      }, {
        age: "15",
        val: 2.00
      }]
    }
  }
};

function calcula() {
  var rows = $('.row');
  var fieldsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("trabalho")[0].
  getElementsByClassName("row"),
    i,
    jobFields = [],
    len,
    newAge = 0,
    selfGender = document.aposentadoria.sexo.value,
    workedDays = 0,
    workedMonthies = 0,
    workedYears = 0;
  var fieldsRule = [];
  var calculateFields = [],
    len = fieldsContainer.length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var thisRow = fieldsContainer[i];
    jobFields[i] = {
      admissionDate: new Date(thisRow.getElementsByClassName("dataAdmissao")[0].value),
      demissionDate: new Date(thisRow.getElementsByClassName("dataDemissao")[0].value),
      ageRule: thisRow.getElementsByClassName("regra")[0].value,
      jobBusiness: thisRow.getElementsByClassName("empresa")[0].value
    };
    //  console.dir(jobFields);
    if (jobFields[i].demissionDate > jobFields[i].admissionDate) {
      jobFields[i].workedYears = Date.DateDiff('yyyy', jobFields[i].admissionDate, jobFields[i].demissionDate);
      // get months after remove years
      jobFields[i].workedMonthies = Date.DateDiff('m', jobFields[i].admissionDate, jobFields[i].demissionDate) - (jobFields[i].workedYears * 12);
      //    console.log('days:' + Date.DateDiff('d', jobFields[i].admissionDate, jobFields[i].demissionDate) );
      // get days worked after remove years/months
      var adate = new Date(jobFields[i].demissionDate);
      adate = new Date(adate.setFullYear(jobFields[i].demissionDate.getFullYear() - jobFields[i].workedYears));
      adate = new Date(adate.setMonth((adate.getMonth()) - jobFields[i].workedMonthies));
      jobFields[i].workedDays = Date.DateDiff('d', jobFields[i].admissionDate, adate); //- (new Date(jobFields[i].admissionDate) - new Date(jobFields[i].demissionDate));
      //   console.log('worked' + i + ":" + jobFields[i].workedYears);
    } else {
      alert("A data de admissÃ£o deve ser anterior Ã  data de demissÃ£o. not less");
      // throw new Error("Conversor :: Admission date must be older than demission date.")
    }
  }
  len = jobFields.length;
  for (i = 0; len > i; i++) {
    fieldsRule[i] = +jobFields[i].ageRule;
  }
  var higherRule = Math.max.apply(null, fieldsRule);
  console.log("higherRule:" + higherRule + " fLen:" + fieldsRule.length);
  len = jobFields.length;
  console.dir({
    "jobf": jobFields
  });
  //console.dir(fieldsRule);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (fieldsRule[i] === higherRule) {
      calculateFields[i] = i;
    }
  }
  console.dir({
    "calcf": calculateFields
  });
  var ageMultiplyBy,
    missingYears,
    jobYearsEnd;
  console.dir(fieldsRule);
  len = calculateFields.length;
  var calcT = {};
  calcT = (selfGender === "M") ? calcT = calcVals.rules.male : calcT = calcVals.rules.female;

  ageMultiplyBy = calcT.defaultRate;
  for (i = 0; len > i; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < calcT.ageRules.length; j++) {
      if (jobFields[calculateFields[i]].ageRule === calcT.ageRules[j].age) {
        ageMultiplyBy = calcT.ageRules[j].val;
        break;
      }
    }
    newAge = jobFields[calculateFields[i]].workedYears * ageMultiplyBy;
    missingYears = newAge - calcT.ageVar;
  }
  console.log('mys:' + missingYears);
  if (missingYears < 0) {
    jobYearsEnd = (+missingYears) * -1;
  }
  len = jobFields.length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    workedYears = workedYears + jobFields[i].workedYears;
    workedMonthies = workedMonthies + jobFields[i].workedMonthies;
    workedDays = workedDays + jobFields[i].workedDays;;
  }
  //invalid id cannot be dupe  document.getElementById("anosTrabalhados").innerHTML = workedYears + " anos";
  for (var m = 0; m < rows.length; m++) {
    console.log('wy:' + workedYears);
    $('.row').eq(m).find('.anosTrabalhados').text(workedYears + " anos");
  }
  //  document.getElementById("anosTrabalhados").innerHTML = workedYears + " anos";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<img src='./img/aviso.png'>" + "VocÃª trabalhou " + workedYears + " anos, " + workedMonthies + " meses e " + workedDays + " dias" + "<br />" + "Faltam " + jobYearsEnd + " anos para se aposentar"
}
$(function() {
  // set defaults for testing
  makedefaults(0);

  $('#calcular').on('click', function() {
    calcula();
  });
  // add a row
  $('#addScnt').on('click', function(e) {
    var rowContainer = $('.trabalho');
    var rows = rowContainer.find('.row');
    var newRow = rows.eq(0).clone(true);
    rowContainer.append(newRow);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
  // remove any row but last one
  $('.trabalho').on('click', '.removerow', function(e) {
    var rowsCount = $('.trabalho').find('.row').length;
    if (rowsCount > 1) {
      $(this).parents('.row').remove();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```